# Find status of shutdown immediate

Tags: oracle

I just issued a `shutdown immediate` command, and it's taking a lot of time. Is there any way, I can find the status of the shutdown task in terms of percentage completed? Or, any kind of status update. It's driving me crazy not knowing what's happening. I know it rolls back uncommited transactions, but I want to know how much of that has been done, how much is left etc.

Comment: It's one of my reasons to use shutdown abort. The instance recovery that is required - and done - during startup can be done in parallel, makig the rollback a lot quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running some flavour of UNIX, tail the alert log to see what is happening with your shutdown

Comment: And why can't you do that on Windows?

Comment: Because Tail is not a command available by default on Windows. Yes there are ways to do this but I was trying to keep the answer as simple as possible.

Comment: You can use mtail for tail functionality in Windows for alert log :)

Comment: Which is not available by default...

Answer (score 1):

You can always check the status from alert log ( or trace log) file located in bdump directory.